# Counting number of string occurrences in a string/array

Tags: ruby, string

I'm expecting to return all words with the max occurrences in a given string. The following code is expected to do so:

```
t1 = "This is a really really really cool experiment cool really "

frequency = Hash.new(0)
words = t1.split
words.each { |word| frequency[word.downcase] += 1 }
frequency = frequency.map.max_by { |k, v| v }
puts "The words with the most frequencies is '#{frequency[0]}' with 
 a frequency of #{frequency[1]}."
```

The output is:

```
The words with the most frequencies is 'really' with 
a frequency of 4.
```

However, it does not work if there are, for example two strings that equal to the max. For example, if I add three `cool`s to the text, it would still return the same output even though the count of `cool` is also equal to four.

It would be nice if you could tell me if those method would work on an array too instead of a string.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
t1 = "This is a really really really cool cool cool"
```

**Step 1: Break your string into an array of words**

```
words = t1.split
  #=> ["This", "is", "a", "really", "really", "really", "cool", "cool", "cool"]
```

**Step 2: Compute your frequency hash**

```
frequency = Hash.new(0) 
words.each { |word| frequency[word.downcase] += 1 } 
frequency
  ##=> {"this"=>1, "is"=>1, "a"=>1, "really"=>3, "cool"=>3}
```

**Step 3: Determine the maximum frequency**

```
arr = frequency.max_by { |k, v| v }
  #=> ["really", 3]
max_frequency = arr.last
  #=> 3
```

**Step 4: Create an array containing words having a frequency of `max_frequency`**

```
arr = frequency.select { |k, v| v == max_frequency }
  #=> {"really"=>3, "cool"=>3} 
arr.map { |k, v| k }
  #=> ["really", "cool"]
```

**Conventional way of writing this in Ruby**

```
words = t1.split
  #=> ["This", "is", "a", "really", "really", "really", "cool", "cool", "cool"] 
frequency = words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word, f|
   f[word.downcase] += 1
end
  #=> {"this"=>1, "is"=>1, "a"=>1, "really"=>3, "cool"=>3} 
max_frequency = frequency.max_by(&:last).last
  #=> 3 
frequency.select { |k, v| v == max_frequency }.map(&:first)
  #=> ["really", "cool"]
```

**Notes**

1. `e = [1,2,3].map #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>`. This tells us that  `frequency.map.max_by { |k,v| v }` is the same as `frequency.max_by { |k,v| v }`.
2. In `frequency = frequency.map.max_by {|k, v| v }`, `frequency` on the right is a hash; `frequency` on the left is an array. It's generally consider bad practice to reuse variables in that way.
3. Often `frequency.max_by { |k,v| v }` is written `frequency.max_by { |_,v| v }` or `frequency.max_by { |_k,v| v }`, mainly to signal to the reader that the first block variable is not used in the block calculation. (As I indicated above, this statement would generally be written  `frequency.max_by(&:last)`.) Note `_` is a valid local variable.
4. `frequency.max_by { |k, v| v }.last` could instead be written `frequency.map { |k, v| v }.max` but that has the disadvantage that `map` produces an intermediate array of `frequence.size` elements, whereas the former produces an intermediate array of two elements.

Answer (score 0):

You've already found the most frequent

```
greatest_frequency = frequency.max_by {|_, v| v }
```

Let's use it to found all the words which have this frequency

```
most_frequent_words = frequency.select { |_, v| v == greatest_frequency }.keys
puts "The words with the most frequencies are #{most_frequent_words.join(', ')} with a frequency of #{greatest_frequency}."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'This is is a really a really a really cool cool experiment a cool cool really'
```

1). Separate string into array of words

```
words = string.split.map(&:downcase)
```

2). Calculate maximum frequency based on unique words

```
max_frequency = words.uniq.map { |i| words.count(i) }.max
```

3). Find combinations of word and frequency

```
combos = words.group_by { |e| e }.map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }.to_h
```

4). Select most frequent words

```
most_frequent_words = combos.select { |_, v| v == max_frequency }.keys
```

Result

```
puts "The words with the most frequencies are '#{most_frequent_words.join(', ')}' with a frequency of #{max_frequency}."
#=> The words with the most frequencies are 'a, really, cool' with a frequency of 4.
```